# Unable to play mapped network media

Tags: macos, windows-8, windows-media-player

I'am trying to play movie files shared from my Mac Server 10.9.1 via smb, I have the drive mapped to Windows 8, I able to read and write to the folder with no problem but unable to play them on any of the media player available. ( Media Player Classic & VLC & SPlayer)
Both Media Player Classic & SPlayer freeze when I try to play them.

On VLC it produce the following error

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///T:/-%3DDance%3D-/Unvsti%20Event%202011.mp4'. Check the log for details.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Can you copy the file to the machine you are trying to play it on and then play it locally? If you can't do this you may not have the proper codecs